# Get lost in so many "that, and, in proportion to" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence

I read [a paper about lake](https://www.pnas.org/content/105/32/11254?etoc=&quot%3B=) and got confused about the following sentence (lower left in page 11256), because it has so many "and", "that", "in proportion to". I do not know which part of the sentence belongs to which word above.

> Short-term bioassays indicated that C-limited (i.e., carbon limited) photosynthesis and algal growth <strike>and</strike> did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P (i.e., phosphorus).

From the view of English grammar instead of knowledge of environmental science, how can I decompose this sentence?  It is frustrating that I konw the meaning of every word in this sentence, but I cannot understand this sentence.

Comment: No wonder you can't understand it.  It is not grammatical.  There is no verb in the first clause.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that the second 'and' should be removed.

Comment: @Jim I'd guess that *that* should be removed.

Comment: @StoneyB - Hmm, that doesn't clarify it for me.  I might have thought 'limited' should be a verb instead of being hyphenated, but the parenthetical seems to preclude that.

Comment: @Jim "Indicated" is often used in scientific contexts to signify "indicated the presence of".

Comment: @StoneyB -  Ahh!!  Perfect.  Makes sense now.

Comment: We need the previous sentence (or perhaps more) to see if 'that' is meant to be a determiner or complementiser here.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't see how the (medical jargon?) usage *His symptoms indicate [that pathogen]* directly relates to OP's text. Apart from a typo (in the original) that I corrected, I really can't see anything that needs "explaining" here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's apparently predicated on a typo.

Comment: StoneyB has a point.  It could be "Short-term bioassays indicated C-limited (i.e., carbon limited) photosynthesis and algal growth and did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P (i.e., phosphorus)," in other words, *short-term bioassays indicated that the critical factor was the availability of carbon, and did not predict etc.*  I skimmed the paper but I'm not sure which correction is what was intended.  I recommend that this question be migrated over to Biology.

Comment: I suppose @StoneyB is right. Following parts constitiute this sentence :  (1) Short-term bioassays indicated the presence of C-limited (i.e., carbon limited) photosynthesis and algal growth; (2) Short-term bioassays did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P (i.e., phosphorus).

Comment: PS: The biological meaning of Sentence (2) means that “There is no presence of P-limited photosynthesis and algal growth.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the comments by StoneyB and the OP have it more correct than the existing answers...

It's not really fair to try to read this sentence without context.

> For the first five years (1969–1974), the ratio of N to P in fertilizer was added at 12: 1 by weight, well above the Redfield ratio, to ensure that phytoplankton had adequate N and P supplies during the period when we were testing the C limitation hypothesis

The sentence you refer to involves data from 1969-1974, with adequate N and P.

I would rewrite the sentence as:

> (Short-term **bioassays**) indicated (carbon-limited **photosynthesis and algal growth**), and (*therefore*) did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P (i.e., phosphorus).

Or, maybe in English that is more clear:

> Algae were carbon-limited so the level of phosphorus didn't affect algal growth.

---

I think what probably happened is that in editing they went from:

> Short-term bioassays indicated that carbon limited photosynthesis

(meaning their tests showed carbon was limiting photosynthesis)

to

> Short-term bioassays indicated carbon-limited photosynthesis

(meaning their tests showed the lake was in a state called 'C-limited/carbon-limited photosynthesis'...which has the same overall meaning as above)

and left in the "that" when converting to the compound adjective.

---

Caveat: I'm a neuroscientist, and plants don't have brains, so this is typically a bit outside my wheelhouse... I'm giving this answer as someone familiar with science writing, not someone familiar with lake eutrophication except as a childhood neighbor to a eutrophic lake with a terrible phosphorus problem resulting from nearby farms.

Comment: Such a great answer! Thanks to explain one possible way how this "strange _that_" came from. I will improve my ability of science writing. Also hope I can do something for the eutrophic lake near your childhood house in the future (if I can be a specialist).

Comment: @TX So far alum treatments, carp removal, stocking better fish, and raising the water level by a foot and a half to match historical levels has helped a bit.

Answer (score -1):

From the view of English grammar, it looks like you have a surplus "and" that creates a loose end in the sentence, or like you're missing part of the sentence that lists a third factor for predicting growth of algal biomass.

It should look like one of the two options:

1. Eliminating the surplus "and": Short-term bioassays indicated that C-limited photosynthesis and algal growth did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P.
2. Adding a third factor: Short-term bioassays indicated that C-limited photosynthesis and algal growth and N-fixing cyanobacteria did not predict the continued growth of algal biomass in proportion to P.

Disclaimer: For the third factor, I just picked up something random from the text...

Answer (score -1):

> Short-term bioassays indicated ***that*** C-limited (i.e., carbon limited)
>   photosynthesis and algal growth and did not predict the continued
>   growth of algal biomass in proportion to P (i.e., phosphorus).

"That" above is being used to indicate the particular C-limited photosynthesis previously mentioned.  It is not being used as a conjunction.  Were you reading it aloud, "that" would be pronounced to rhyme with the word "bat," not to rhyme with the word "bet."

> Short-term bioassays indicated that C-limited (i.e., carbon
>   limited) photosynthesis and algal growth and did not predict the
>   continued growth of algal biomass ***in proportion to*** P (i.e.,
>   phosphorus).

"In proportion to" means "to a relative size comparable with."  It's saying that short-term bioassays didn't forecast the ongoing increase of algal biomass in a manner proportionate to P.

Comment: Or it _could_ be an example of incorrect grammar (which looks the favourite to me; your reading _is_ grammatical, but doesn't seem to construe well). Obviously, more context is needed to decide.

Comment: Thanks! I think your explanation about "that" not being a conjunction is appropriate. In addition, I suppose StoneyB's comment can also be helpful.

Comment: Either "that" _or_ "and" is superfluous. The presence of "that" means that the photosynthesis and growth have some effect which is not stated if "and" is present as well. If "that" is omitted then indication of photosynthesis and growth are one outcome of the studies and the prediction is another.